# Listing the hours between two timestamps and grouping by those hours

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery

I am trying to ascertain a count of the couriers that are active every hour of a shift using the  the start and end times of their shifts to create an array which I hope to group by. Firstly, when I run it I'm given epoch times back, secondly, I am not able to group by the hours array.

Does anyone have any solutions that they would kindly share with me?

**
SELECT

GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY(CAST(fss.start_time_local AS TIMESTAMP), CAST(fss.end_time_local AS TIMESTAMP) , INTERVAL 1 hour) as hours,
#COUNT(sys_scheduled_shift_id) AS number_schedule_shift,

FROM `just-data-warehouse.delco_analytics_team_dwh.fact_scheduled_shifts`    AS fss

#GROUP BY hours
**

For your reference the shift data for the courier is structured like so

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

To calculate how many couriers have been active at least one minute in every hour I would do it like this:

```
SELECT 
  CALENDAR.datetime
  ,SUM(workers.flag_worker) as n_workers
FROM (

-- CALENDAR
SELECT
    cast(datetime as datetime) datetime
FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY('2022-01-01T00:00:00', '2022-01-02T00:00:00'
  ,INTERVAL 1 hour)) AS datetime
) CALENDAR


-- TABLE of SHIFTS
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT * , 1 flag_worker FROM
  UNNEST(
       ARRAY<STRUCT<worker_id string , shift_start datetime, shift_end datetime>>[
         ('Worker_01', '2022-01-01T06:00:00','2022-01-01T14:00:00')
         ,('Worker_02', '2022-01-01T10:00:00','2022-01-01T18:00:00')
       ]
    )
    AS workers
    )workers
  ON CALENDAR.datetime < workers.shift_end
    AND DATETIME_ADD(CALENDAR.datetime, INTERVAL 1 hour) > workers.shift_start
  
GROUP BY CALENDAR.datetime
```

The idea is to build a calendar of datetimes and then join it with a table of shifts.

Instead of hours, the calendar can be modified to have fractions of hours. Also, there may be a more elegant way to build the calendar.

Comment: Thats great, thanks so much. I was able to use 'SELECT AS STRUCT' statement to query the table as opposed to using the array which worked a treat. Thanks so much